# PHP : Get Icon from apk

Tags: php, android, resources, icons, apk

finally i could get information about apk like version , package, name & ... with this source :

[PHP APK Parser](https://github.com/tufanbarisyildirim/php-apk-parser)

icons path in apks are not unique in all apps, in some "icon.png" and other "ic_launcher.png" and in different folders. here is my problem , how i can get icon anyway, without error and bug and without tools like "apktool" and "appt" ?

actually i wanna get and view icons directly in my small site

sorry for my bad English

Comment: So you want to somehow extract the app icon from an APK file?

Comment: yes of course if its possible

Comment: https://github.com/tufanbarisyildirim/php-apk-parser now supports getting resource files like icon etc.

Answer (score -2):

Use this with pclzip.lib.php Library..

```
<?php
require_once 'pclzip.lib.php';
$path = 'path/to/apk';
$default = 'path/to/default_icon.png';
$destination = 'path/to/destination.png';

$zip = new PclZip($path);
$data = $zip->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_BY_PREG, "/res\/drawable(|-ldpi|-mdpi|-hdpi|-xhdpi)\/(ic_launcher|icon|logo|icn|ic|i).(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)/isU", PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, './tmp', PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);

$icn = end($data);
$icn = $icn['filename'];

//now you have path to the icon in ./tmp folder

if(!empty($icn)){
copy($icn, $destination);
} else{
copy($default, $destination);
}

foreach($data as $dt){
@unlink($dt['filename']);
}
?>
```

I hope this will work for you..

**EDIT:**
*At the time of my first answer, there wasn't a reliable method/library available. So, I created a temporary method. Which was working for me.
Now, we have a better library, you should use that.*

Library: [php-apk-parser](https://github.com/tufanbarisyildirim/php-apk-parser) by [Tufan Barış YILDIRIM](https://github.com/tufanbarisyildirim)

Example: [ApkResource.php](https://github.com/tufanbarisyildirim/php-apk-parser/blob/master/examples/ApkResource.php)

Comment: Actually, It works only with those apk file which contains icon.png or ic_launcher.png (or jpg or gif)

Comment: Not reliable at all, it assumes specific names of icon file.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't reliable. But, it was working for me at the time. Btw, thank you for pointing that out. I have edited my answer.